# Folding Problem

Tags: applications, low-dimensional-topology

Here's one for you topologists out there to show your field has practical application.  I have covers for my air conditioner units that are shaped like 5 sides of a rectangular sold with dimensions 31" x 31" x 29", as shown in the figure included in the link below.  Every summer, I have to remove them and store them away in their storage boxes which measure only 19.5" x 13" x 2.5 ".  It takes me forever to figure out how to fold them, and I never really do a very good job.  The cover is made of a faux-leather kind of material that's not easy to fold.  So my question is, who can provide me with directions for folding the covers most efficiently and neatly to fit in the storage boxes.

Note the constraints that the 10" x 4.25" emblem which is 3" from the top of the front face can't be folded.  Also, the thick edging on the border of the top face is not easy to fold, so the fewer folds required in the top face, the better.

[image: A photo of one of the covers]